# Two Tables with cascade delete

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

```
[tbl_Records_DR] PK DAutoID.
[tbl_Records_DR_Explain] PK DRefer_ID
```

1. I want to create a foreign key between these tables.
2. I want to be able to cascade delete when I remove a record from [tbl_Records_DR].

I'm creating my tables programmatically (only).

Here's what I currently have that works well creating the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [tbl_Records_DR] ( " _
& "[DAutoID] int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL " _
& ", [Hub_Unique_Name] nvarchar(30) DEFAULT ''  NULL " _
& ", [DStatus] nvarchar(30) DEFAULT ''  NULL " _
& ", [DDate] datetime NULL " _
& ", [DTime_Start] datetime NULL " _
& ", [ReportCreatedFrom] nvarchar(5) DEFAULT 'DR'  NULL);")

CREATE TABLE [tbl_Records_DR_Explain] ( " _
& "[AutoID] int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL " _
& ", [DRefer_ID] int PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL " _
& ", [DExplain] nvarchar(700) DEFAULT ''  NULL " _
& ", [ImportCompleted] bit DEFAULT 0 NULL;")
```

Thanks,
ADawn

Comment: Do you already have the field defined in `tbl_Records_DR_Explain` that points to `tbl_Records_DR`? Microsoft Docs has detailed information on creating foreign keys: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-2017#create-a-foreign-key-in-a-new-table

Comment: Why are you creating tables in a program like this? Seems like a lot of effort to write code that can't run more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ALTER TABLE` to change one of this tables and add `FOREIGN KEY`. Hope i help you

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
ALTER TABLE [tbl_Records_DR_Explain]
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_AutoID
    FOREIGN KEY ([DRefer_ID])
    REFERENCES [tbl_Records_DR] ([DAutoID])
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Edit

```
CREATE TABLE [tbl_Records_DR_Explain] (
[AutoID] int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL 
, [DRefer_ID] int  NOT NULL 
, [DExplain] nvarchar(700) DEFAULT ''  NULL 
, [ImportCompleted] bit DEFAULT 0 NULL
    CONSTRAINT fk_AutoID
    FOREIGN KEY (DRefer_ID)
    REFERENCES [tbl_Records_DR] ([DAutoID])
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    )
```

http://rextester.com/NZH15043

Comment: Do I ALTER TABLE after I create it? Or is there a way to do what you suggest when the table is created?

Comment: Added edit to include the FK in the original creation of table instead of altering table after